# Who wrote the "Seder Vehilchos Korban pesach rishon beketzarah"

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-bavli, maseches-pesachim

In Pesachim 57b (right before the 5th chapter) there is a page containing a summery of laws pertaining to the Korban Pesach.

Who wrote it?

Comment: See also pesachim 99a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have heard that it was first published in the [Amsterdam edition of the Talmud in (5474 - 5477) 1714 - 1717](http://vjweb.cloudapp.net/Listing/Details/199286/Talmud-Bavli-Tractate-Berakhot-Zerayim-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-Amsterdam-Samuel-Marcheses-Raphael-de-Palacio-Judah-Aryeh-17141715). It is attributed to Rabbi Yosef Shmuel of Cracow the father of Rabbi Yehuda Aryeh Leib who published this edition of the Amsterdam Talmud.

> In 1714, R. Judah Aryeh Leib ben Joseph Samuel, av beit din of
> Frankfurt-am-Main, arranged to have the Talmud printed in Amsterdam by
> Samuel ben Solomon Marquis and Raphael ben Joshua de Palacio. They
> began printing with Berakhot, but were forced to discontinue printing
> in 1717 due to the approbations issued for the 1697-1699
> Frankfurt-am-Oder edition of the Talmud. These haskamot functioned as
> rabbinic prohibitions, or copyrights, preventing rival editions from
> being issued for a specified period of time.