# Piskei Hilchos Pesach

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-pesachim, pesach-sheni

In [Maseches Pesachim 57b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=57b&format=pdf), the last page of of the fourth chapter ends abruptly halfway through the page, followed by "הדרן עלך מקום שנהגו **וסליקא לה פסח ראשון**." The rest of the page is filled by a large paragraph titled פיסקי הלכות פסח ראשון בקצרה.

The same thing appears later on [Maseches Pesachim 99a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=99&format=pdf) at the end of the ninth chapter, this time saying "הדרן אליך פסח שני" and the following paragraph titled פיסקי הלכות פסח שני בקצרה.

Why does the hadran at the end of these chapters make it seem as though a masechta was completed? Why is it then followed by this summary paragraph, unlike anywhere else in shas (that I am aware of)?  Do we know who wrote this paragraph?
(This sounds like multiple questions but I feel like they probably have the same or related answers)

Comment: There used to be a custom to split Pesachim (plural) into two parts: chapters 1234&10 in the first half and 56789 in the second half. Perhaps this is an artifact of that system

Comment: very similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30757/759 probably should mark that as duplicate of this new one

Comment: @DoubleAA In fact, [the title page of the Bomberg edition](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=20546#p=1&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) refers to them as two separate masechtos. The Meiri, in his introduction to Pesachim, writes that the Geonim created this split. || That the paragraphs are there on 57b and 99a is probably just because a large blank space like that cries out for something to fill it; in earlier editions, such as Bomberg and its successors, they're in fact blank.